# Создание Автомата с Напитками java

Tags: java, scanner

Всем привет. Помогите исправить. Не могу понять, как прописать чтоб в конце подсчитывало сумму  и названия выбранных напитков (Например: Вы заказали 5 напитков. Общая стоимость - 200).
А так же сканер позволяет вводить только один напиток.

```
инструменты для использования:

1) enum (напитки)

2) константы (цены)

3) static (общая стоимость)

4) switch (выбор напитка)


Задание:

#1 сделайте enum DrinksMachine, умеющего делать КОФЕ, ЧАЙ, ЛИМОНАД, МОХИТО, МИНЕРАЛКУ, КОКА_КОЛУ;

#2 Сделайте класс Drinks, где константами задайте цену напитку;

#3 Произведите подсчет количества изготовленных напитков и общей суммы, которую должен заплатить клиент;

#4 Сделайте способ приготовления каждого напитка;

#5 Сделайте switch-case оператор, который будет производить напиток (вызывая соответствующий метод) в зависимости от выбора клиента;

#6 Разместите возможность выбора напитка для пользователя и в зависимости от выбора делайте ему напиток;

#7 Пользователь должен иметь возможность заказать несколько напитков

#8 И наконец клиент должен увидеть, сколько денег он должен заплатить;
```

Мое Решение:

Вот enum:

```
        COFFEE("Кофе"),
        TEA("Чай"),
        LEMONADE("Лимонад"),
        MOJITO("Мохито"),
        MINERAL("Минералка"),
        COLA("Кока-кола");
    
        private String title;
    
        DrinksMachine(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    
    }
```

Вот клас Drinks:

```
public class Drinks {
    final double coffee = 19.99;
    final double tea = 11.99;
    final double lemonade = 15.00;
    final double mojito = 29.50;
    final double mineral = 9.99;
    final double cola = 10.00;

    public double getCoffee() {
        return coffee;
    }
    public double getTea() {
        return tea;
    }
    public double getLemonade() {
        return lemonade;
    }
    public double getMojito() {
        return mojito;
    }
    public double getMineral() {
        return mineral;
    }
    public double getCola() {
        return cola;
    }

}
public class Drinks {
    final double coffee = 19.99;
    final double tea = 11.99;
    final double lemonade = 15.00;
    final double mojito = 29.50;
    final double mineral = 9.99;
    final double cola = 10.00;

    public double getCoffee() {
        return coffee;
    }
    public double getTea() {
        return tea;
    }
    public double getLemonade() {
        return lemonade;
    }
    public double getMojito() {
        return mojito;
    }
    public double getMineral() {
        return mineral;
    }
    public double getCola() {
        return cola;
    }
}
public class Drinks {
    final double coffee = 19.99;
    final double tea = 11.99;
    final double lemonade = 15.00;
    final double mojito = 29.50;
    final double mineral = 9.99;
    final double cola = 10.00;

    public double getCoffee() {
        return coffee;
    }
    public double getTea() {
        return tea;
    }
    public double getLemonade() {
        return lemonade;
    }
    public double getMojito() {
        return mojito;
    }
    public double getMineral() {
        return mineral;
    }
    public double getCola() {
        return cola;
    }

}
```

Вот main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runApp();
        System.out.println("Колличество напитков: " + DrinkPreparing.getCounter());
    }

    public static void runApp() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        DrinksMachine[] drinkTypes = DrinksMachine.values();

        DrinksMachine userDrinkType = null;
        System.out.println("count license: " + DrinkPreparing.getCounter());

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter drink type from list: " + Arrays.toString(drinkTypes));
            String userValue = scanner.nextLine();
            userValue = userValue.toUpperCase();


            for (DrinksMachine drinkType : drinkTypes) {
                if (drinkType.toString().equals(userValue)) {
                    userDrinkType = DrinksMachine.valueOf(userValue);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (userDrinkType != null) {
                break;
            }
        }


        switch (userDrinkType) {
            case COFFEE: {
                new DrinkPreparing();
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + DrinksMachine.COFFEE.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Стоимость: ");

            }

            case TEA: {
                new DrinkPreparing();
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + DrinksMachine.TEA.getTitle());
                break;
            }

            case LEMONADE: {
                new DrinkPreparing();
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + DrinksMachine.LEMONADE.getTitle());
                break;
            }

            case MOJITO: {
                new DrinkPreparing();
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + DrinksMachine.MOJITO.getTitle());
                break;
            }
            case MINERAL: {
                new DrinkPreparing();
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + DrinksMachine.MINERAL.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Стоимость: ");
                break;
            }
            case COLA: {
                new DrinkPreparing();
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + DrinksMachine.COLA.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Стоимость: ");
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Счетчик:

```
public class DrinkPreparing {
    private static int counter;

    public DrinkPreparing() {
        counter++;
    }

    public static int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }


}
```

Comment: Преподавателя, кто дал такое задание, нужно уволить) Полный бред, непонятные имена, какие-то обязательные `switch`... Что это такое вообще? Я бы на вашем месте возмутился. Как можно класс с ценами назвать `Drinks`? Это всё равно, что назвать курицу - свиньёй. Enum'ы, которые служать для хранения констант и каких-то простых манипуляций с данным, назвать `DrinksMachine`... Так должен класс называться, а не enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваше задание сформулировано некорректно. Сначала вы должны четко описать бизнесс правила, потом спроектировать решение, а потом приступать к реализации. Вы начали с реализации и поэтому получился совершенно нерациональный избыточный код.

```
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Здравствуйте! Сделайте свой заказ.");
                DrinksMachine drinksMachine = new DrinksMachine();
                drinksMachine.start();
                drinksMachine.process();
                System.out.println("До свидания!");
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class DrinksMachine {
    
        private double totalCost = 0.0;
    
        private List<Drink> drinks = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public void start() {
    
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            System.out.println("Пожалуйста, введите название напитка либо нажмите Enter для выполнения заказа : " + Arrays.toString(Drink.values()));
    
            while (true) {
                String userInput = scanner.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
                if (userInput.isEmpty()) break;
                try {
                    Drink drink = Drink.valueOf(userInput);
                    this.drinks.add(drink);
                    this.totalCost += drink.getCost();
                } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели некорректное название напитка. попробуйте еще раз.");
                }
            }
        }
        
        public void process() {
            for (Drink drink : drinks) {
                System.out.println("Возьмите Ваш " + drink.getTitle());
                System.out.println("Стоимость: " + drink.getCost());
            }
            System.out.println("Колличество напитков: " + this.drinks.size());
            System.out.println("Общая стоимость : " + this.totalCost);
        }
    
        public double getTotalCost() {
            return totalCost;
        }
    
        public List<Drink> getDrinks() {
            return drinks;
        }
        
    }

public enum Drink {

    COFFEE("Кофе", DrinkCost.COFFEE),
    TEA("Чай", DrinkCost.TEA),
    LEMONADE("Лимонад", DrinkCost.LEMONADE),
    MOJITO("Мохито", DrinkCost.MOJITO),
    MINERAL("Минералка", DrinkCost.MINERAL),
    COLA("Кока-кола", DrinkCost.COLA);
    
    private final String title;
    private final double cost;

    private Drink(String title, double cost) {
        this.title = title;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

}

public class DrinkCost {    
    public final static double COFFEE = 19.99;
    public final static double TEA = 11.99;
    public final static double LEMONADE = 15.00;
    public final static double MOJITO = 29.50;
    public final static double MINERAL = 9.99;
    public final static double COLA = 10.00;    
}
```

Не стесняйтесь задавать вопросы, если таковые появятся

Comment: Большое спасибо. Только есть нюанс. У Вас цены прописаны в enum, а по заданию, должны быть прописаны в классе Drinks отдельно.

Comment: @MrInkognito именно поэтому я и говорю вам, что задание написано криво. вы же понимаете, что название  напитка и его цена  - одна сущность. то есть в идеале это должен быть отдельно класс с переменной, хранящей название напитка и переменной, хранящей цену. разделить название и цену тоже самое , что в школьном журнале написать имена детей в один журнал, а фамилии в другой. не то, чтобы это невозможно, но это противоречит даже здравому смыслу. если очень хотите, то можно просто из енама обращаться в сторонний класс со стоимостью (если не понимаете как - пишите, покажу)

Comment: Если честно, я только начинаю изучать - покажите, если можете :)
И еще не используется switch-case оператор, который будет производить напиток.

Comment: @MrInkognito легко, смотрите исправленный ответ

Comment: @MrInkognito что касается свитч - кейс, то лучше вообще про него забудьте. он в решении просто не нужен , потому что он ничего не делает (в вашем решении тоже). подумайте сами, зачем вы его используете? крутить счетчик напитков? так для этого не нужен свитч, потому что вы это делаете независимо от напитка (какой бы кейс не отработал, это все равно нужно делать, т.е. его моно вынести за пределы свитча и ничего не изменится). вывести название и стоимость - аналогично. в таком случае все выносится за пределы свитча и свитч остается пустым. внимание , вопрос: что конкретно делает свитч?

Comment: Я согласен с Вами, но по заданию нужно использовать хоть один свитч кейс, могут снизить оценку из-за его отсутствия.

Comment: @MrInkognito по поводу ошибок - их там нет, поскольку код я скопировал из среды разработки. удалите все и скопируйте заново. должно получиться 3 класса и енам. по поводу свитч - кейс мен в принципе непонятна эта формулировка: Сделайте switch-case оператор, который будет производить напиток (вызывая соответствующий метод) в зависимости от выбора клиента; вопрос - какого метода? метод приготовления напитка? тогда в задаче должна быть описана логика приготовления, потому что метод описывает действие. у вас нет никаких методов, описывающих такую логику. и в задании ничего такого нет.

Comment: @MrInkognito все условия задания с точки зрения бизнесс-логики выполняются. поймите простую вещь: нельзя написать условный оператор, если нет условия. в этой задаче нет условия, чтобы писать свитч. если вы опишите логику, соответствующую по функциональности свитчу, то я помогу вам ее написать, но ее здесь нет. снизить оценку - так себе аргумент. я не знаю где вы учитесь и кто и зачем вам пишет такие задачи. но этот вопрос нужно задавать вам своему преподавателю, тут я не помогу, потому как не экстрасенс))

Comment: Спасибо большое! :)

Comment: Дмитрий, не могли бы Вы еще помочь с этим заданием: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1486618/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82-java

Comment: @MrInkognito ваш вопрос закрыли не просто так. код, который вы предоставили очень плохо соотносится с заданием, а задание сформулировано нечетко. ваш метод matrix не компилируется в части if (m == n) - эти переменные просто не объявлены, а массив , который передается в параметрах этого метода, игнорируется при выполнении метода. для проверки, является ли матрица квадратной, достаточно одного цикла. зачем вы писали этот код вообще непонятно. метод, расчитывающий среднее ароифметическое, должне возвращать его значение, а не печатать в консоль. на такое юнит тесты невозможно написать в принципе

Comment: Сможете мне подсказать, как правильно будет сделать это задание? Мой телеграм: @od_rada, возможно там будет проще и удобнее.

Comment: Дмитрий, добрый вечер. Подскажите, все ли правильно. "Сделайте метод, который будет принимать на вход двухмерную матрицу (двухмерный массив) и проверять, является ли она квадратной."
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] myArr = matrix();
        method(myArr);
    }

    private static void method(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
        }
    }

Comment: private static int[][] matrix() {

        int[][] arr = new int[4][3];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++) {
                if (arr.length == arr[i].length) {
                    System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Wrong");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
        return arr;
    }

Comment: @MrInkognito я бы с радостью вам помог, но я не понимаю, что вы делаете. вот подумайте: перед вами стоит задание на да/нет, т.е. узнать является ли матрица квадратной. тут два варианта: да или нет. почему ваш метод возвращает двухмерный массив??? как возвращение двухмерного массива может ответить на вопрос, является ли матрица квадратной? почему вы в методах постоянно и куда угодно тыкаете System.out.println? у вас что в задаче сказано, чтобы вы написали метод, который что-то выведет в консоль? нет же. тогда почему это выглядит так??? посему у меня вопрос: какую задачу вы решаете?